# JavaScript - Function throws error in IE, but works fine in Chrome, Firefox etc

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this JS function

```
function trans(key, replace = {})
{
  let language = 'de';
  if(window.currentLanguage !== undefined) {
    language = window.currentLanguage;
  }
  let translation = key.split('.').reduce((t, i) => t[i] || null, window.translations[language]);

  for (var placeholder in replace) {
      translation = translation.replace(`:${placeholder}`, replace[placeholder]);
  }

  return translation;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc.
But in IE (Mode 11) it throws this error:

> ")" expected

Actually, there is no error, otherwise it would not work in Chrome etc.  And I also checked all brackets. Each opening bracket is being closed. How can I re-write this function, that it works in IE (Mode 11) also?

Comment: IE probably doesn't support parameter default values.

Comment: On what line does IE throw the error?

Comment: I don't think IE supports template strings, either.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_Compatibility - probably only one of your problems. I don't get why people write code for IE and don't expect and read up on the 23847562348576234785 pitfalls that it has :S

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters

Comment: This code contains four features that are not supported in IE. You need to familiarize yourself with the new syntactical features that have been added from ES6 onward and understand that they are not supported in IE.

Comment: currently IE doesn't support default value, you can check browser compability on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

you can change your code to ES5 to fix it

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comments. I re-wrote the function now for IE compatibility with your help!